# Magento 2 REST api authorize.net integration

Tags: rest, payment, checkout, magento2, authorize.net

I'm using Magento 2.1 REST Api in my website, and currently working on the payment system (Authorize.net).

Is it possible to set payment details (credit card) and place an order with Authorize.net through the Magento Api after setting up Authorize.net in the admin?